# Can a field be isomorphic to its subfield?

Tags: field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $K(X)$ be the field of its rational functions.

Now let $\phi \in K(X)$ be a rational function such that $K(\phi) \neq K(X)$.

Now, since $\phi$ is transcendental over $K$, $K(\phi)$ is isomorphic to $K(X)$.

Is this a correct example of a field being isomorphic to its subfield?

Are there any other examples?

Comment: Yes. But there are easier examples, like $K(X_2, X_3, \ldots) \subsetneq K(X_1, X_2, \ldots)$...

Comment: @Zhen: Do you think yours is easier than $K(X^2) \subset K(X)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are algebraically closed fields of the same uncountable cardinality and of the same characteristic, then they also have the same transcendence degree over their prime field, and are therefore isomorphic.

Comment: You mean "cardinality", right?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I changed "cofinality" to "cardinality".