# Can a field be isomorphic to its subfield but not to a subfield in between?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

A question related to this one [Can a field be isomorphic to its subfield?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113581/can-a-field-be-isomorphic-to-its-subfield): are there field extensions K/E and E/F such that K and F are isomorphic but E is not isomorphic to them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We construct an example. There are many.

Let $t_0,t_1,t_2,t_3,\dots$ be a countably infinite collection of algebraically independent transcendentals.

Let $F$ be the algebraic closure (in $\mathbb{C}$) of $\mathbb{Q}(t_1,t_2,t_3,\dots)$ and let $K$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(t_0,t_1,t_2, t_3,\dots)$. Let $E=F(t_0)$.

Comment: Dear André, thank you for the answer. It follows that there exist two fields (E and F, above) which can be embedded to each other BUT not isomorphic. This may be a NEW equivalence relation in the category of fields. If it is indeed new, we may call it the Nicolas-equivalence.

Comment: Why are $F$ and $E$ not isomorphic though? Isomorphism over what field? $F$-isomorphism ? $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphism? Are they not isomoprhic as rings (fields) or are they not isomorphic as $F$-fields

Comment: It has been a while, and I am post dinner and wine. They are not isomorphic as fields, since $F$ is algebraically closed but $E$ is not.

Comment: why one being algebraically closed but the other not imply they are not isomorphic though?

Comment: Why is $E$ not algebraically closed?

Comment: (i) $\sqrt{t_0}\not\in E$ (the $t_i$ are algebraically independent; (ii) Any isomorphism preserves any algebraic property, for example the property of having a root.

Comment: thanks a lotttt!

Comment: I credited you for your answer ;)

Comment: You are welcome. I had left some gaps to fill in, and you correctly focused on these.